# How to manage the bridge table generated automatically by Entity Framework Core 5?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using **Entity Framework Core 5**, for M:N relationship, I created tables including the OrderProduct bridge table generated in SQL Server automatically. After that, I need to manage OrderProduct. How can I update the bridge table, **OrderProduct** using EF Core 5?

```
// Order
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderFulfilled { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

// Product
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

```
// Need to manage ProductOrder with properties below
public class ProductOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; } 
        public int OrderId { get; set; }           
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; } 

    }
```

Comment: Explained in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#joining-relationships-configuration

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks. You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who wants to use **usingEntity** for customizing the join table. I found this from [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore5.com/whats-new-in-ef-core-5).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
        .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
        .UsingEntity<PostTag>(
            j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId),
            j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId),
            j =>
            {
                j.Property(pt => pt.PublicationDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                j.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
            });
}
```